# Backbone/Marionette form with list of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, user-interface, marionette.js

Using Backbone/Marionette, I'm building a simple widget that looks like:

[image]

I'm hoping to get some feedback on my approach because I think I may be doing it wrong.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbarreiros/mdwcco0j/)

```
// widget/invites/person.js
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: ''
    }
});

// widget/invites/people.js
var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});

// widget/invites/personField.js
var PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template(...),
    hasSiblings: false,
    initialize: function(opts) {
        this.hasSiblings = opts.hasSiblings || false;
    },
    templateHelpers: function() {
        return {
            id: this.model.cid,
            showDel: this.hasSiblings
        }
    },
});

// widget/invites/form.js
var FormView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: _.template(...),
    childView: PersonView,
    childViewOptions: function() {
        return {
            hasSiblings: (this.collection.length > 1)
        };
    },
    childViewContainer: '.values',
    ui: {
        'addBtn': '.add-name',
        'removeBtn': '.del-name',
        'wrap': '.values'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.addBtn': 'addFormRow',
        'click @ui.removeBtn': 'removeFormRow'
    },
    addFormRow: function(ev) {
        var name;
        ev.preventDefault();

        if (this.collection.length === 1) {
            // also rerender first input to include remove button
            name = this.ui.wrap.find('[name="person[]"]').get(0).value;
            this.collection.reset([{name: name}, {name: ''}]);
        }
        else {
            this.collection.add({name:''});
        }
    },
    removeFormRow: function(ev) {
        var id, model;
        ev.preventDefault();

        id = $(ev.currentTarget).data('id');
        model = this.collection.get(id);
        this.collection.remove(model);

        if (this.collection.length === 1) {
            // rerender first input so it doesn't have remove button
            name = this.ui.wrap.find('[name="person[]"]').get(0).value;
            this.collection.reset([{name: name}]);
        }
    }
});
```

*Note, the list is saved by clicking a <kbd>Submit</kbd> button (not shown in mockup), as there will be other fields in the form as well.*

---

The code works, but consider the following workflow:

1. User enters "John Doee" in first input

   - `Collection: ['']`
2. User clicks "add", and enters "Sally Something" in the second input

   - `Collection: ['', '']`
3. User realized they spelled "John Doe" (two e's) and fixes it

   - `Collection: ['', '']`

or consider an existing list being edited:

1. Collection: `['John Doe', 'Sally Something', 'Austin Powers']`
2. User removes "`Austin Powers`"

   - Collection: `['John Doe', 'Sally Something']`
3. User updates "John Doe" to "Dr. John Doe"

   - Collection: `['John Doe', 'Sally Something']`

I'm using `collection.add()` and `collection.remove()` to trigger the view to update itself, but the collection doesn't always reflect the data on the screen. **Is that okay?**

Additionally, I did try adding a hook for `blur` which grabbed every value and reset the collection, but it seemed too brute force. Hence, my doubt about this approach.

Any thoughts or other approaches?

Comment: Are there missing values in your first example ? And I will your questions Is that okay by another question : If your collection to an external service and there is missing values would it be a problem ? I'm guessing it would be since you're not sending what the user see/think is in the collection.

Comment: "Are there missing values in your first example?": Yes and no. When the "add" button is clicked, an empty model is added to the collection to trigger the view to be updated. When a user changes a value, I'm not touching the model because the view doesn't need to be updated.

Comment: "... is missing values would it be a problem?": Not in this context. My thinking is that when the form's submit button is clicked, I tell the view to grab all of the values, update the collection and then call save() to actually save the values to the DB.

Comment: Ohh you didn't included the submit button in your jsfiddle or the ui preview here. If you're only saving on the submit button it's I think if you do not alway update your model. The thing is you will need to be sure that being out of sync would not cause some weird bug.

Comment: Thanks Marc-Andre. At the moment, the model isn't being used by anything else, so it shouldn't be a problem. I couldn't find similar examples online so I was just wondering if there were other, possibly better, approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. A View's Model represents "state", not data. This is a subtle distinction that wasn't apparent to me at first. The Collection **should** match the View, blank values and all.

When it comes time to save the list, the Collection's `toJSON` method can be overridden to omit any blank models.

I [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jbarreiros/mdwcco0j/5/) my original jsfiddle to show values being saved on `blur`.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Person,
  toJSON: function() { /*filter out empty models*/}
});

var PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  ...
  events: {
    'blur input': 'onChange', //calls model.set('name', input value)
  },
  triggers: {
    'click .del-name': 'remove:form:row' //calls collection.remove(...)
  },
  ...
});

var FormView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  events: {
    'click @ui.addBtn': 'addFormRow' //calls collection.add({name: ''})
  },
  collectionEvents: {
    add: 'onRowAdded'  //rerender first row to show delete button
  },
  ...
});
```